# Can someone explain the significance of this code snippet [Javascript]

Tags: javascript

```
function play()
{
if (typeof Game_Interval != "undefined")
clearInterval(Game_Interval);
Game_Interval = setInterval(paint, 60);
allowPressKeys = true;
}
```

What exactly is Game_Interval and why isnt it declared as a variable in the code?
The above mentioned function is a part of a snake game program using javascript and HTML canvas tag.

Comment: Game_Interval is likely some kind of JavaScript object on which clearInterval and setInterval operate. Of course, there's no way to know without seeing all the code. You've shared only a small part out of context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval` calls a function (`paint()` in your case) at regular intervals (`60ms` in your case) and returns a Number, representing the ID value of the timer that is set. Use this value with the clearInterval() method to cancel the timer.

Since `Game_Interval` is not declared, javascript will implicitly declare it as a global variable.

Comment: Makes sense. Cheers!